# how to remove folder names from url using htacsess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**how to remove folder names from URL using htaccess**

This is the code I was tried

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)food 
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ food/$1 [L]
     </IfModule>

site.com/food/one.php   TO site.com/one.php
```

The above code works fine for a single folder name (ex: food)  but I have more than 10 folders
(food,  health,   beauty....) I want to remove that names too ...this code not working more
than one folder name please help me out... THanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just restructure your code to remove the directories and move the PHP files into the document root?   Rewrite rules for removing that many directories are going to get complex and not perform well.

Comment: What you ask is impossible: how should the rewriting engine decide which folder it should rewrite your request to if no such information is contained in the requested URL? You need _something_ you can evaluated. Once you have answered what that _something_ should be you can implement your rule set.

Comment: @arkascha do you mean that not possible to remove folder names.... only one folder name is possible  am i right ?

Comment: Technically that is correct, though I'd say that this does not really make sense for a single folder name too, since that would make everything else in your project _outside_ that single folder name unreachable. Since _everything_ would get rewritten into that folder. Which most likely is not what you want.

Comment: Again my question: can you name any aspect by which the rewriting engine can distinguish between requests to resources in two folders (for example in "food" and "health")? Once you can answer that you can also implement a rule for that. Without answer there is nothing the rewriting engine can do for you.

Comment: It looks like you asked this again and it now has an answer there: [hide (remove) folder names in URL rewrite Rules Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964128/hide-remove-folder-names-in-url-rewrite-rules-not-working)  I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.